# Excel VBA - while-statement that only ends after the with-statement

Tags: excel, vba, while-loop

It appears that I am unable to place a while-statement within a with-statement if the 'wend' is placed only after 'end with'.

```
Sub Testing()

Dim i As Integer
i = 1

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

While i <= 4

.Cells(i, 20).Value = "5"

End With  'get error, as the wend for the while is not yet found

i = i + 1

Wend

End Sub
```

Does this mean that I cannot use the with-statement if it contains a while-statement that only ends after the with-statement?

Comment: Move the `End With` after the `Wend`. Note: `While...Wend` is old-fashioned. Use a `For` loop.

Comment: Or the `While` before the `With`. There is presumably more to the real code as this `With` statement is pointless?

Comment: Yes there is more to the real code, I understand in this example above it might seem obvious to just place the while before the width as it has no effect on result, but in my actual code I need to do a few things to the sheet before before entering the while-statement, but I also need to end the with before while is done, as I move to another workbook within the while-statement.

Comment: Then do a with before the while and then two withs within the while. What do you expect to happen if you end a with inside a loop and the loop comes back around to before you end the with? It ended the with already it's not going to go back up through the code find the with and reapply it. Even if it did do that it horribly obfuscates what is actually happening in the code.

Comment: Thank you very much Warcupine, you provided an alternative and explained why it does not work. I understand now that in my current code when it loops a second time, i am trying to end something that has not started again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I need to do a few things to the sheet before before entering the while-statement, but I also need to end the with before while is done*

You can't have that, it's not legal syntax. Blocks have a *start* and an *end* token, and they cannot be intertwined - no matter what kind of block we're looking at.

Illegal:

```vb
If condition Then
    '...
    With something
        '...
End If
        '...
    End With
```

That does not mean blocks cannot be nested as needed!

Legal:

```vb
If condition Then
    With something
        '...
    End With
End If
```

The compiler "reads" the code top-to-bottom. When it encounters a block statement (such as `With`), it expects the next `End {Block}` statement to close that block - if that's not the case, a syntax error is thrown and the code doesn't compile.

So you simply cannot have `End With` before the `Wend` token (note: `Do While...Loop` would be [preferred](https://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ObsoleteWhileWendStatement); also given that the number of iterations is known at compile-time, a `For...Next` loop should be used instead of manually incrementing a counter in the loop body).

A `With` block is sometimes practical, but it's never *really* needed.

In this particular case, `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")` is dereferencing a worksheet that exists in `ThisWorkbook`; if that sheet exists in `ThisWorkbook` at compile-time, then [you could use its CodeName instead](https://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/SheetAccessedUsingString), and thus avoid the need to dereference a worksheet that is already globally accessible from anywhere in your project - set the `(Name)` property of that module to e.g. `DataSheet`, and then you can refer to it directly, like this:

```
DataSheet.Cells(i, 20).Value = "5"
```

Unless your real code is nesting `With` statements (which shouldn't be done, for sanity's sake!), then moving the `End With` token outside of the loop to legally nest the two blocks would suffice. If code outside the loop could also use a `With` block, then it can have it too:

```
For i = 1 To 4
    With DataSheet
        .Cells(i, 20).Value = "5"
    End With
Next

With DataSheet
    'other code
End With
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Testing()

Dim i As Integer
i = 1

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    Do While i <= 4
      .Cells(i, 20).Value = "5"
       i = i + 1
    Loop
End With

End Sub
```